# Reset a file after resolving a merge

Tags: git

I accidentally edited a file in a merge conflict that I didn't mean to edit in a branch that I am in, and now I cannot revert the file back to the origin/master. Unfortunately I didn't catch it until after I had already pushed the commit to the remote branch. Here are the steps that I have followed in an attempt to fix the accidental commit of "a.cpp":

```
git diff origin/master a.cpp # Shows there are diffs
git checkout origin/master a.cpp 
git diff origin/master a.cpp # Shows there are NO diffs
git status # Shows that a.cpp has changed (which it should)
git add a.cpp
git status #shows that the files is staged for the commit
git commit -v # Verbose shows that nothing has changed!!!?
git diff origin/master a.cpp # Shows there are diffs AGAIN
```

It seems that since I resolved the conflict in the file, it is refusing to be updated to what is in origin/master. How can I force it to be updated to to origin/master?

Answer (score 0):

```
git status # Shows that a.cpp has changed (which it should)
git commit -v # Verbose shows that nothing has changed!!!?
```

It seems that a `git add .` step is missing there. You need to update the index before committing said index.

The [`git checkout  [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutem-p--patchlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203)  updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).

Comment: Sorry, I was doing an add. Just updated the question.

Comment: @user985030 what a git status *after* the git add and before the commit shows?

Comment: It shows the file is staged. I updated the question too.

Comment: @user985030 would a `git commit -m "a message"` work better?

Comment: The problem is that the diffs show I've added a file but that there are no changes. When there are indeed changes.

Comment: @user985030 still, does the `git commit -m "a message"`records a new commit? If yes, can you do a `git show @` to check that new commit content?

Comment: @user985030 but you do see a new commit, right? What is its new SHA1? Can you use the new SHA1 in `git show --pretty="" --name-only SHA1` in order to see if that lists a.cpp?

Comment: It does show the commit. I'll update my question with the SHA when I get back to machine. Thanks